# gpu pulsating 0 to 100% very fast while training tensorflow model

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, tensorflow

While training a tensorflow convnet model on gpu, the gpu utilization keeps on pulsating 0 to 100% in about 0.5 seconds.

Is this a desirable effect? or something is wrong in my model.
I need to utilize full gpu power because of my big model and big images. 
Please help.

Note:- I am using TfRecorddataset for input pipeline.
Below is  the code for making input pipeline;-

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
  features = {"image": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
              "mask": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value="")}
  parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, features)
  return parsed_features["image"], parsed_features["mask"]


# In[5]:


tfRecord_file = "/home/tarun26mi/carvan_challenge/tfrecords/"
tfFiles = [tfRecord_file+f for f in listdir(tfRecord_file)[:-2] if f[-9:]== "tfrecords"]
totalEamples = len(tfFiles) * EXAMPLE_PER_FILE
itr_for_one_epoch = totalEamples/BATCH_SIZE
f_print(totalEamples,opstring="Total Example: ")
f_print(itr_for_one_epoch,opstring="Iterations for one epoch ")
f_print(tfFiles)


# In[6]:


dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(tfFiles)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
dataset = dataset.repeat()
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
img, mask = next_element
img = tf.decode_raw(img,tf.float32)
mask = tf.decode_raw(mask,tf.float32)

img = tf.reshape(img,shape=[-1,IMAGE_ROWS,IMAGE_COLS,NUM_CHANNELS])
mask = tf.reshape(mask,shape=[-1,OUTPUT_ROWS,OUTPUT_COLS,1])
```

Comment: No, it is not a desirable effect, but to determine what happens there's not enough information here. Could be that you are stuck on transferring data from CPU to the GPU, maybe you're CPU bound in your input pipeline, maybe you are disk bound ...

Comment: I have edited the que and provided the code for making input pipeline. Please help